# Как создать двигающейся ромб?

Tags: python, tkinter

На пространстве формы изображен календарь за апрель текущего года с горизонтальным расположением недель. Дни недели подписаны. Метка в виде ромба циклически движется по датам, начиная с последней, в обратном направлении с дискретом времени 0.7 сек. Запуск движения – команда главного меню, остановка – кнопка «Стоп», что приводит к установке рамки на последнюю дату.

И как правильно понять: *Запуск движения – команда главного меню*?

Код:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkcalendar import * 
root= Tk()
root.title("Calendar") 
root.geometry("600x400")

ca = Calendar(root,selectmode="day",year=2021, month=4,day=12)
ca.pack()

Stop = Button(root, text="Стоп") 
Stop.pack(pady=20)
```

Comment: `И как правильно понять: Запуск движения – команда главного меню?` - значит у вас должно быть главное меню в окне, при нажатии на пункт главного меню должно запускаться движение.

Comment: Ну и скорее всего предполагается, что нужно самостоятельно календарь создать. Для одного месяца это не очень сложно сделать. Я бы делал через Canvas, потому что "метка в виде ромба" (Label) не будет прозрачной, поэтому лучше рисовать как многоугольник (через create_polygone) поверх нарисованного календаря.